# disable button on master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

On my master page I have a rad menu.

On a page that uses the master page I am able to make the menu visible with this coded

```
Me.Master.FindControl("mymenu").Visible = True
```

Do you know how to make one of the buttons on the menu disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it worked when I put it in a Page_LoadComplete function

```
 Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
        Dim menu As Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenu = DirectCast(Me.Master.FindControl("RadMenu1"), Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenu)
        menu.FindItemByText("Menu1").Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming that the menu item on your RadMenu with the text "Menu1" is the item you wish to disable, this is a correct implementation of the requested functionality

Answer (score 1):

Kick it really hard and have it end up in a wheelchair?

Or do you mean to ask 'Do you know how to disable one of the buttons on the menu?'

Maybe your looking for

```
Me.Master.FindControl("mymenu").Enabled = False
```

But I'm not sure that property exists for your control...

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do you know how to disable the button "myButton" in the menu?

Comment: Of what type is MyButton?

Comment: Hi - my rad menu has four buttons that if you hover a button  then a menu appears. I'm trying top disable that